# The usage of "an"

Tags: grammar

In Visual Studio 2019 there is an error report "initial value of reference to non const must be an lvalue" why is there an "an" instead of "a"? Should not be a typo of the team.

Comment: Because they're pronouncing it as "an elvalue"?

Comment: Because *everyone* pronounces it as "an elvalue".